# C, two kinds of functions

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I always see two kinds of functions like the following:

```
void Function_1(
    int** buff
    )
{
    int* retNb = null;
    retNb = (int*) malloc(42 * sizeof(int));
    *buff = retNb;
}

void Function_2(
    int* retNb
    )
{
    retNb = (int*) malloc(42 * sizeof(int));
}
```

What is the difference between `function_1` and `function_2` ? What are their use case ?

Comment: Bad example, I guess. Second function does nothing but memory leak.

Comment: They should be the same with the technical difference of one being an array of pointers and you have just set the first element to the int[42], and the other being just a pointer and you have allocated it 42 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really big difference, they're really different - by ANY means.
Let's keep it simple:

```
 void Function_1(int** buff)
```

Parameter in function 1 is a pointer to a pointer to an int named buff and what this function does is the following:

```
int* retNb = null;
```

Declaring an int pointer called `retNb`, the assignment to `NULL` here is really not necessary, though, because next line is the following:

```
retNb = (int*) malloc(42 * sizeof(int));
```

`retNb` is called to get the value returned from `malloc`. `malloc` allocated `42*sizeof(int)` spot in memory and returned it to `retNb` and now it can be treated as a simple array with 42 integers and can be accessed with square brackets `[]` as `retNb[i]`.

```
*buff = retNb;
```

in pointers `*` is the way to get to the content of the address in the variable (variable == pointer in this case) so when using `*buff` when buff is `**buff` (a pointer to a pointer) you're actually asking for the pointer buff points to. Let's say we have the code:

```
int** myPointerToPointer = NULL;
int* myPointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
*myPointer = 4; //or myPointer[0] = 4;
printf("%d\n", *myPointer);
myPointerToPointer = &myPointer;
printf("%d\n", *(*myPointerToPointer));
printf("%d\n", &myPointer);
printf("%d\n", *myPointerToPointer);
```

then the output would be:

```
4
4
SOME_ADDRESS
SAME_ADDRESS
```

because the first printing is the value of `myPointer` (4) and the second is the value of the value of `myPointerToPointer` which value is `myPointer` which value is 4 :P
Third and fourth outputs are the same two because the address of `myPointer` is actually where `myPointerToPointer` is pointing to.

About the second function:

```
void Function_2(int* retNb)
```

It gets an int pointer - not a pointer to a pointer - just a pointer - means it contains an address of an integer variable that can be accessed with the opeartor `*`.

```
retNb = (int*) malloc(42 * sizeof(int));
```

this line is assigning dynamic memory (again 42 times `sizeof(int)`) and now can be treated as a regular int array with 42 spots - BUT that's the only thing it does, it won't have anything point to it, just assign memory and that's it.

Hope you understand :P

Answer (score 0):

In function two u are have a pointer to an array of 42 ints. 
int function 1 you set buff to point to this array.